# Format the controls on "Screen.ActiveDatasheet" with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm tryng to avoid to set properties via the query desing builder per the image below
[image]

After this line of code (Open the Query)

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery cstrQueryName, acViewNormal, acReadOnly
```

I would like to format dynamically the columns (like change caption, the format when it's a number...)

I did try the following but all failed

```
Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).Caption.Value = "Assembly"
Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).Properties("Caption").Value = "Assembly"
Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "Assembly"
```

Here the complete source

```
Sub ViewASSYPer(TypeofCode As String) '
    Const cstrQueryName As String = "ViewASSYPerType"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf  As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim sqlStr As String

    On Error GoTo ViewASSYPer_Err:
    CloseDeletequery cstrQueryName

Set db = CurrentDb

'rebuild query

sqlStr = "SELECT ASSY_TABLE.assy_number, ASSY_TABLE.revision, ASSY_TABLE.description,"
sqlStr = sqlStr & " ASSY_TABLE.target_weight, assy_weight_table.assy_weight, assy_weight_table.assy_fs, assy_weight_table.assy_bl, assy_weight_table.assy_wl"
sqlStr = sqlStr & " FROM ASSY_TABLE INNER JOIN assy_weight_table ON ASSY_TABLE.assy_number = assy_weight_table.assy_number "
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE (((ASSY_TABLE.CollectorTypeCode) = """ & TypeofCode & """));"

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(cstrQueryName)
qdf.SQL = sqlStr

DoCmd.OpenQuery cstrQueryName, acViewNormal, acReadOnly

 Screen.ActiveDatasheet.AutoResize = True

'    'Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(1).Properties("Caption").Value = "Rev:"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(1).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "Description"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(3).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "Target Weight"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(4).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "Weight:"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(5).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "FS Arm"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(6).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "BL Arm"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(7).Field.Properties("Caption").Value = "WLArm"
'
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).Field.Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
'    Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).Field.Properties("DecimalPlaces") = 3

     Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).SetFocus
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFreezeColumn

Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ViewASSYPer_Err_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ViewASSYPer_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ViewASSYPer_Err_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Column headers are named by the control name. So when you change that name, the column header will display that name.

```
qdf.Fields(0).Properties("Name").Value = "Assembly"
```

But be aware that names must be unique. You cannot name two columns the same name. There might be other limitations regarding special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).Caption = "Assembly"
```

Or create and use a form in datasheetview with your query as source.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve partially my issue. Did apply the properties on the QueryDef.
But still have some issues 'Properties not found' on these line of code.

```
qdf.Fields(4).Properties("Caption").Value = "Total Weight:"
qdf.Fields(5).Properties("Caption").Value = "FS Arm"
qdf.Fields(6).Properties("Caption").Value = "BL Arm"
qdf.Fields(7).Properties("Caption").Value = "WL Arm"

qdf.Fields(5).Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
qdf.Fields(6).Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
qdf.Fields(7).Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
```

Here the updated source code.

```
Sub ViewASSYPer(TypeofCode As String) '
    Const cstrQueryName As String = "ViewASSYPerType"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf  As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim sqlStr As String

    On Error GoTo ViewASSYPer_Err:

    CloseDeleteSearchResultquery cstrQueryName

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'rebuild query

    sqlStr = "SELECT ASSY_TABLE.assy_number, ASSY_TABLE.revision, ASSY_TABLE.description,"
    sqlStr = sqlStr & " ASSY_TABLE.target_weight, assy_weight_table.assy_weight, assy_weight_table.assy_fs, assy_weight_table.assy_bl, assy_weight_table.assy_wl"
    sqlStr = sqlStr & " FROM ASSY_TABLE INNER JOIN assy_weight_table ON ASSY_TABLE.assy_number = assy_weight_table.assy_number "
    sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE (((ASSY_TABLE.CollectorTypeCode) = """ & TypeofCode & """));"

    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(cstrQueryName)
    qdf.SQL = sqlStr

qdf.Fields(0).Properties("Caption").Value = "Assembly"
qdf.Fields(1).Properties("Caption").Value = "Rev:"
qdf.Fields(2).Properties("Caption").Value = "Description"
qdf.Fields(3).Properties("Caption").Value = "Target Weight"
qdf.Fields(4).Properties("Caption").Value = "Total Weight:"
qdf.Fields(5).Properties("Caption").Value = "FS Arm"
qdf.Fields(6).Properties("Caption").Value = "BL Arm"
qdf.Fields(7).Properties("Caption").Value = "WL Arm"

qdf.Fields(5).Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
qdf.Fields(5).Properties("DecimalPlaces") = 3

qdf.Fields(6).Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
qdf.Fields(6).Properties("DecimalPlaces") = 3

qdf.Fields(7).Properties("Format") = "Fixed"
qdf.Fields(7).Properties("DecimalPlaces") = 3

    DoCmd.OpenQuery cstrQueryName, acViewNormal, acReadOnly

  Screen.ActiveDatasheet.AutoResize = True

     Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Controls(0).SetFocus
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFreezeColumn

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Exit Sub


ViewASSYPer_Err_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ViewASSYPer_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ViewASSYPer_Err_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: More information From Querydef solution proposal. Using the local variable windows I did look at the 8 items properties count under each one. The count properties does vary. For the field index 0 to 2 there is 35 properties. I did found the caption properties in item 26. For the other fileds there is 32 properties but no caption properties. That where the code fails. Does someone know why the count of properties may vary?